# Why are the nightmare.js examples not working?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, nightmare

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect; // jshint ignore:line 

describe('test yahoo search results', function() {
  it('should find the nightmare github link first', function*() {
    var nightmare = Nightmare()
    var breadcrumb = yield nightmare
      .goto('http://yahoo.com')
      .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
      .click('.searchsubmit')
      .wait('.url.breadcrumb')
      .evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('.url.breadcrumb').innerText;
      });
    expect(breadcrumb).to.equal('github.com');
  });
});
```

Why does this test always evaluate to true?

This test evaluates to true even if I change the comparison value.  If I add a console.log before the expect, it does not print, which makes me thing the test is never being evaluated and that a null response is true for chai.  I am running node v4.2.2, and the latest versions of nightmare and expect.  I run the test from the terminal using mocha index.js (the name of this file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function*` and `yield` is a ES2015 feature called [***Generators***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).

There's a additional note after the example on the README:

> Please note that the examples are using the [mocha-generators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-generators) package for Mocha, which enables the support for generators.

So you need to install the package and add this to your code:

`require('mocha-generators').install();`

Comment: I wonder if there's any reason their examples don't have that line of code in it.